# SQLite Query issue

Tags: objective-c, sql, sqlite

I have a DB having 3 tables like

**Name(PK_NameId, FK_ContactId, FK_FavId, length)**

**Contact(PK_ContactId)**

**Favourites(PK_FavId)**

In my iPhone app, there are various options(criterias) to search the name as user can select multiple names, user can select multiple contacts, user can select multiple favourites & also user can select length like 0-10, 10-20 etc. Also user can click search button without any criteria to get all the names.
I am new in SQLite & wants to create a query for searching the name by considering above all cases without the if-else condition through coding which takes less amount of time for query execution.
I know one option to check which criteria user is selected & apply if-else condition but it is not too good so I want to handle it through query.
If anyone knows it then please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution using the following way -

```
NSString *strQuery;    
strQuery = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT N.PK_NameId FROM Name N inner join Contact C on C.PK_ContactId = N.FK_ContactId inner join Favourites F on F.PK_FavId = N.FK_FavId where ((1)"];
```

after this, I checked the null value of each selection type(name, contact, list) & append the query to the original query. Finally complete the query using the closing brace which was I opened after where clause in main query.

```
strQuery = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@)", strQuery];
```